# how to change the source of an image dynamically when it's clicked using shiny tags$script

Tags: jquery, r, image, tags, shiny

Using the following code I tried to change the src of the image img2 when its double clicked.

```
 tags$script("
        $('#img2').on('dblclick', function(){ alert('dbl');
this.attr('src', 'absolute path to image'); } )")
```

The alert works, but the image doesn't get changed. What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tag$script but your JQuery code looks good it should change your image on the fly when executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry, I was wrong, I should have seen that first...

you see your pointer 'this' that you use in you Jquery code... it should be:

$(this) then everything should be fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Lavigne958 suggested, `$(this)` should fix it.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(

    fluidPage(

      tags$img(id = "img2", src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/0d6/blue-flowers-with-macro-4-1400913.jpg"),

      tags$script("
        $('#img2').on('click', 
                      function(){
                        $(this).attr('src', 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/4aa/blue-butterfly-1378813.jpg'); 
                      } )")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){}
)
```